# Proof that the twin prime constant is irrational (reference request)

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, open-problem

It seems intuitively clear that the [twin prime constant](http://oeis.org/A005597)
$$
C_2 = \prod_{p > 2} \left(1-\frac{1}{(p-1)^2} \right) \approx 0.66016
$$
is *irrational*.

Can anyone please give a reference to a short proof of this (e.g. in an introductory number theory textbook)?

If this is in fact an open problem, could you please give a reference to some source explicitly stating so?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the irrationality of this constant is an open problem.

Comment: Thanks Greg! This may explain why I could not find a reference :)

Comment: This logic is unassailable :D